# Form Submission with email to get routed via Netlify

Tags: email, netlify

I have a new site created and planning to host it on Netlify,  I am thinking of creating a form to collect customer Testimonials from the site and email me on my company email address I have read that Netlify does not provide email service. Got inputs like using Zapier integration or free mail service like Zoho.

What other options do I have to make this work? Anyone using Netlify and got email forwarding activated?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using any SMTP email service and just send the email using PHP or any other code way.

For example here is how to send emails with PHP using Gmail SMTP.
https://pepipost.com/tutorials/send-an-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-using-php/

Or how to use the AWS SMTP and PHP.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-php.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give this a try and confirm if it works.

Comment: If it does, dont forget to mark it as solved and upvote :)

Comment: Sure, Definitely! :)